# How can I train a deep learning model with coordinates X, Y, and images?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

My task is cephalometric landmark localization.
I have images path with coordinates show in this data frame.

| filename | X1 | Y1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| /Images_data/binary0006.png | 89 | 80 |
| /Images_data/binary0008.png | 37 | 70 |
| /Images_data/binary0007.png | 50 | 76 |
| /Images_data/binary0003.png | 55 | 92 |
| /Images_data/binary0005.png | 91 | 64 |
| /Images_data/binary0004.png | 100 | 76 |

How to prepare dataset for training in model.fit ?
I try to create images dataset for training with ImageDataGenerator.

```
  train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  label_mode=None,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

But now I'm stuck, because I don't know How to match coordinate with images.

Comment: So, are you saying there is some common feature in all of those images, at that given location, and you want the model to predict that location from an arbitrary image?  If the feature has a distinctive shape, wouldn't this be better as an image matching process?  I'm not sure it's really a keras problem.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, I want to try this task with Keras first because right now I'm still a beginner of python programming, but I'll definitely use Pytorch in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `flow_from_dataframe` method of `ImageDataGenerator`.

1. Load your DataFrame containing the file paths and coordinates.

```py
import pandas as pd
data_dir = "images/"
df = pd.read_csv("dataframe.csv")
df = df.sample(frac=1, random_state=9)
print(df)
```

2. Create ImageDataGenerator

```py
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
)
```

3. Flow from DataFrame

```py
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
img_height, img_width = 100, 100
batch_size = 32
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=df,
    directory=data_dir,
    x_col="x_col",
    y_col=["X1", "Y1"],
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="raw",
    shuffle=True,
    seed=9,
    subset="training"
)
```

Here, x_col is set to "x_col" to specify the column containing file paths, and y_col is set to ["X1", "Y1"] to specify the columns containing the coordinates. The class_mode is set to "raw" to indicate that the labels are continuous values.

Now, you can use train_generator in the model.fit function:

```py
model.fit(train_generator, epochs=num_epochs, ...)
```